# How to access elements of 2nd, 3rd page after navigating manually in a VBA launched chrome browser

Tags: vba, selenium, one-time-password

I want to navigate to a new page manually and then click a button in that page thru VBA script.

As of now client logs in to the page fills up the details and bypasses captcha using chrome extension. Now he needs to automate OTP filling and 3 successive clicks in 3 successive pages for which i need to do like this. In IE using Shell window i am able to do the stuff but captcha cannot be used there.As such i want to start chrome thru webdriver to aquire browser's handle then let user do the entry in page bypass captcha.In the next page I will fill the OTP from VBA.I am presuming browser reference will remain same the URL will keep changing.

This is how i am opening the browser. Browser opens user does the entry and navigates to next OTP page. Here how do i get the element textbox to fill it up.

```
Dim d As Webdriver
Set d = New ChromeDriver
Const URL = "https://www.google.com/"
d.Start "Chrome"
```

How to go about this.

Pls give some direction

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know what some text of the new window will be e.g. the title then you can use the following method from examples by the author Florent BREHERET. You will however, need to code in for launching a pre-saved profile with the cookies/add-in associated, or install the add-in as part of the launch. There are examples of how to do this by myself and YasserKhalil on StackOverflow (and possibly by others).

```
Private Assert As New Selenium.Assert

Private Sub Windows_Switch()
  Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
  
  driver.Get "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows"
  driver.FindElementByCss(".example a").Click
  
  'Switch to a new window
  driver.SwitchToNextWindow
  Assert.Equals "New Window", driver.title
  
  'Switch to the previous activated window
  driver.SwitchToPreviousWindow
  Assert.NotEquals "New Window", driver.title
  
  'Stop the browser
  driver.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Seems like it is doable. I declared webdriver as procedure global var. And i am using same in different macros.Without considering which page is currently loaded I am just clicking the buttons if it is there it will click.I will continue this tomorrow.